# What is a "Vorentscheidung"?

Tags: meaning, noun, vocabulary

After the match Dortmund–Bayern München (1:0) of yesterday, I read that this victory has marked a "Vorentscheidung" for the race to the German football championship. But what exactly is meant by "Vorentscheidung"? Do there exist different meaning variants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=vorentscheidung) translate it as *preliminary decision*.

After the defeat of Munich there is now a 6 points difference between Dortmund and Munich and four games are left in this season. That means Dortmund needs two wins and one draw to win this season. And that's very likely. Only if Dortmund looses two of their games Munich get a chance.

So *Vorentscheidung* means that we believe to know the final result.

You can hear *Vorentscheidung* also during a game. Let's say in the 70th minute a team shoots the 2-0. Then you are pretty sure that they will win this game.

*Vorentscheidung* can happen anywhere. The only condition is that the final outcome isn't clear yet but it seems to be obviously who will be the winner.

Comment: `Vorentscheidung` is also used for a contest where the contestants have to qualify (e.g. `Vorentscheidung zur Eurovision Teilnahme`)

Comment: @dgw I believe this would more often be called `Vorentscheid`.

Comment: For the soccer match in which one team goes ahead 2-0 in the 70th minute, you wouldn't use "preliminary decision". You can write something like, "Any **hopes** for a comeback that Spurs had **were dashed** when Rooney put ahead United 2-0 in the 70th minute." Or, "The game had seesawed back and forth for the longest time but when Nowitzki sunk a fallaway jumpshot in the 4th quarter, drawing a foul to make it a three-point play, you could **stick a fork in** Miami: **they were done**." Disassemble the anodyne German compound noun and turn it into a colorful verbal phrase in English.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel I agree with you, but I have seen the other as well.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to your last question: yes, different meanings exist. [The Duden has this to say about it](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorentscheidung):

> a. vorbereitender Beschluss, erste [richtungweisende] Entscheidung
>
> b. (besonders Sport) Stand eines Wettkampfes, Zwischenergebnis, mit dem sich die endgültige Entscheidung bereits abzeichnet

**b** was already explained to you in another answer. **a** is different in that it actually is a *definite* decision (there are no more chances for a different outcome), but it is a decision which was made in preparation of another one, which will be made based on the preliminary decision (and probably others).

An example for **a** would be (as has been mentioned): winning a national contest to qualify for an international one.